# In LC-3 Language, stores user name and password and then checking the name and password

Tags: assembly, lc3

In LC-3, Store username and password, and then move on to asking the password if it matches the saved username when you insert username. If you insert the username and it does not match the saved username, you are again asked to insert the username through a message. The program ends when it fails three times.

Likewise, password is configured the same.

I don't know how to start by constructing this as LC3 language.

Comment: Unfortunately, "how can I get started" questions are not a very good fit for this site, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254933/answering-questions-which-ask-for-effort-guidance-not-spoon-fed-solutions.  It's probably better to seek assistance from an instructor, tutor, classmate, etc.

Comment: You need to decompose the problem into managable piece parts.  Solve each one, and recompose the parts into an overall solution.  Do it in C first, then translate to assembly.